# Is it good to use AutoMapper?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

is it a good practice to use AutoMapper for creating ViewModels in MVC4?

Are big MVC projects using AutoMapper or is there a better way?

Are there any disadvantages when using AutoMapper?

If I have to discuss with other developers about using AutoMapper, which arguments can I use to convince them?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: voting for reopening this question: I've asked for best practice and not to discuss about the problem. It's a question meaning "How to do it the best way" and not "Is it really a good idea to do... ?"

Comment: And what do you think will happen when two people disagree on the best way?

Comment: So this argument would count for any best practices questions...

Comment: Yes, it does. Best practice questions generally are not constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoMapper is a great tool when used for simple conversions. When you start using more complex conversions, AutoMapper can be invaluable. For very simple conversions you could of course write your own conversion method, but why write something that somebody already has written?

As for performance, AutoMapper uses some clever tricks (including dynamically compiled code) to ensure that its performance is still very good.

Answer (score 2):

One quite large system using AutoMapper is nopCommerce.

It is using Autofac (IoC container) and Automapper in its plugin architecture. Highly extensible but like anything your choice of components shoud be based on what your project is.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I've used AutoMapper in several MVC3/4 applications and it can be really useful! There is a performance penalty when compared to doing manual mapping, but for most web applications this penalty is minimal and well worth the price.

AutoMapper will save you writing a LOT of boring mapping code and it will probably spare you from a few nasty bugs as well. The only thing you must be aware of is that the mapping uses convensions and you really want to follow these. As long as you do that, AutoMapper is a great tool!

Comment: How so? You still have to write the same boring code in the mapping profile?

Comment: Haha! Commenting on an 8 year old answer :-) Well, writing a mapping profile is much faster than writing a complete set of mapping code. Most of the mapping is normally done automatically using conventions.